# make work cakePHP site in subdirectory on live server

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

cakePHP site is working on live ,files are under public_html folder.
I'm now making mobile site version on that site by copying whole website into a sub directory public_html/m/.... .

But I'm unable to access controllers.
The main site controllers are working for sub directory 'm' site.
Might be, its routing issue.not sure .no idea what to do?

Comment: `by copying whole website into a sub directory public_html/m/` Why would you do that - copy and paste is almost never a good idea.

Comment: yes obviously not a good idea . actualy m.site will be the clone of main site excluding non-necessary functions .

Comment: You need to keep the two CakePHP folders separated. So you have to redirect the maindomain.com eg to /CakeDesktop/ and mobile.maindomain.com to /CakeMobile/ (only example). Thats to be done in your hosting controll panel, not in Cake...